# How does content in an a-element affects semantics, screen readers and search engines?

Tags: html, seo, semantics, screen-readers

Let's say I have a list of articles on a preview page of a blog. I want the whole area of each entry to be clickable. In *HTML5* this is a possible solution with valid markup:

```
 <a href="details/mypost">
    <article>
        <header>
            <h1>My Post</h1>
        </header>

        <p>This is just the teaser. Read more here …</p>
    </article>
</a>
```

My questions are:

- Is this semantically a link or an article or somehow both regarding the *w3* defintion?
- How is this content read by search engines and screen readers? Is it just a link or do they treat it as an article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Semantically, you have a link which contains an `article`. The `a` element doesn’t change the meaning of its descendants.

(It might make more sense to include the link in the `article`, e.g., `<article><a>…</a></article>`.)

There is no reason to assume that search engines should have any problem with this (but discussing this is off-topic on SO; it might be on-topic on [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/).)

How exactly screen readers read this depends on the specific screen reader and its version.

Some years ago, the [The Paciello Group/Steve Faulkner made a test](http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2011/06/html5-accessibility-chops-block-links/) with some screen readers, [documented on the test page](http://www.html5accessibility.com/tests/blocklink.html). Only some minor issues were found: sometimes VoiceOver repeated text (which resulted from a more general bug), and Jaws/NVDA/Window-Eyes sometimes treated the single link as separate links.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I like the idea of `<article><a>…</a></article>`. Let me ask you: Is this a good way to make a whole element to link to another page or would it be better to add an `a`-element in the container (with really just the link and some text like "read more" and use JavaScript to make the whole `article` clickable?

Comment: If you are sure that the whole snippet should be clickable, I’d say it’s a good way (using plain HTML instead of JS). However, I’m not so sure if it’s a good idea to have the whole snippet clickable in the first place: it makes it harder to select/copy specific text in this snippet, and the link text gets pretty long (which might be a problem for screen reader users that use a function to list all links on the page). But it probably depends on the specific case. Discussing the impact on users might be on-topic on [ux.se].

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll take that last topic to the UX site. Thanks.