# I want to make a circle button with text and different text on hover CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a circle button (I was thinking submit button or link to another page) that has a label/text on it, and then when you hover it has different text. I've been able to find tutorials on all of these things individually, but together I can't quite get them to work.

Currently I have:

HTML

```
<div class='button'>
     <a href='activities.php'>
          <div class='text'> hello world </div>
          <img src="/Images/budapest.jpg">
     </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.button img { /*http://codeitdown.com/css-round-buttons/*/
    display:                block;
    width:                  30vmin;
    height:                 30vmin;
    line-height:            50px;
    border:                 2px;
    border-radius:          50%;
    color:                  #000000;
    text-align:             center;
    text-decoration:        none;
    background:             #000000;
    font-size:              20px;
    font-weight:            bold;
    z-index:                1;
}
.text{
    display:                block;
}
.text:hover {
    display:                none;
    z-index:                2;
}

.button input[type=submit].nav  {
    font-family:            'Optima', sans-serif;
    height:                 auto;
    width:                  auto;
    background:             #111111;
    border-radius:          1vmin;
    color:                  #FFFFFF;
    font-size:              2vmin;
    z-index:                2;
}
```

The button currently is the image I want - yay, and indeed redirects to the correct page. However, the text "hello world" always shows (instead of only when on hover), is above the image (not on top of it), and I can click on it or the button to redirect me. Also, how do I get the text to change when I hover?

**Update**

The remaining problem is that the text is not inside the button/image.

**My Code**

```css
.button img { /*http://codeitdown.com/css-round-buttons/*/
  display:    block;
  width:     30vmin;
  height:     30vmin;
  line-height:   50px;
  border:     2px;
  border-radius:    50%;
  color:     #000000;
  text-align:    center;
  text-decoration:  none;
  background:    #000000;
  font-size:    20px;
  font-weight:   bold;
  z-index:     1;
}
.button .text-after {
  display:     none;
}
.button:hover .text-after {
  display:     inline;
}
.button:hover .text-before {
  display:     none;
}
```

```html
<div class='button'>
  <a href='activities.php'>
    <span class="text-before">Before</span>
    <span class="text-after">After</span>
    <img src="/Images/budapest.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Credit to: http://codeitdown.com/css-round-buttons/  | http://bavotasan.com/2011/circular-images-with-css3/ | http://codepen.io/ChrisUpjohn/pen/HBgiI

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `<div>` inside `<a>` (*Worst nightmare! Division inside a link? Block inside an inline?*).

Secondly use two text containers like this:

```
<div class='button'>
     <a href='activities.php'>
          <span class="text-before">Before</span>
          <span class="text-after">After</span>
          <img src="/Images/budapest.jpg">
     </a>
</div>
```

Use this CSS:

```css
.button .text-after {display: none;}
.button:hover .text-after {display: inline;}
.button:hover .text-before {display: none;}
```

**Updated Snippet**

**My Code**

```css
.button img { /*http://codeitdown.com/css-round-buttons/*/
  display:    block;
  width:    30vmin;
  height:    30vmin;
  line-height:   50px;
  border:     2px;
  border-radius:   50%;
  color:    #000000;
  text-align:   center;
  text-decoration:  none;
  background:    #333333;
  font-size:      20px;
  font-weight:   bold;
  z-index:     1;
}
.button .text-after {
  display:     none;
}
.button:hover .text-after {
  display:     inline;
}
.button:hover .text-before {
  display:     none;
}

.button a {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 89.6875px; /* should be the width of image*/
  line-height: 89.6875px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

.button img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class='button'>
  <a href='activities.php'>
    <span class="text-before">Beforexd</span>
    <span class="text-after">After</span>
    <img src="/Images/budapest.jpg">
  </a>
</div>
```

The above is what I did, but unfortunately it didn't work. I don't know why, but I can give you a different solution:

```css
.round-img-button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.round-img-button a,
.round-img-button img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.round-img-button a {
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
}

.round-img-button a .after {
  display: none;
}

.round-img-button:hover a .after {
  display: inline;
}

.round-img-button:hover a .before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="round-img-button">
  <a href="#">
    <span class="after">Hover</span>
    <span class="before">Normal</span>
  </a>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: [Actually a block level element inside an anchor is absolutely valid for HTML5.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1827965/1456376) It is on the other hand [not allowed for other inline elements.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6061869/1456376)

Comment: @insertusernamehere Still, a nightmare. Semantically wrong! You cannot put a box inside water! Can't imagine!

Comment: Let's assume the `div`-element has semantic meaning or take an `article` within the anchor: "*Semantically, you have a link which contains an article. The `a`-element doesn’t change the meaning of its descendants.*", see: [How does content in an a-element affects semantics, screen readers and search engines?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25360826/2711071). This is also discussed on Google's Webmaster Central Help Forum: [SEO - How does Google react with HTML 5 block links?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/HOVcX-hK6hc/discussion)

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the text display issue, but the text is still not inside the button. Any other ideas?

Comment: @swallis1 Reply with your current fiddle link, we'll fix it.

Comment: @insertusernamehere I give up! `:P` And I commit suicide if I see any other block level tag inside a `<a>` tag.

Comment: Haha, sorry :D And please don't. Cheers from Germany to the UK. :)

Comment: If I don't put the block level tag inside a <a> tag then how?

Comment: And you can say, through India! `:D`

Comment: @swallis1 I just gave it in the answer right? What else do you want? Show the fiddle, and we'll fix the bug, which you just said.

Comment: @swallis1 Chec your question now!

Comment: @swallis1 I gave you a solution. Have a look!

Comment: What doesn't seem to change anything? Did you see the second one? Did you click on Run Code Snippet and see?

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
.button a:hover .text {
    display:                none;
    z-index:                2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example `http://jsfiddle.net/josedvq/Jyjjx/45/` can be answer for your question.

```
<div class="round-button"><div class="round-button-circle"><a href="http://example.com" class="round-button">Button!!</a></div></div>
```

Comment: **This doesn't answer the question.**